# how to implement overlay for cordova camera plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to implement an overlay to show borders when a camera is being accessed.  This way I can have the user frame the image in the way I need.  Any idea how to do this using cordova camera plugin?  My application is in Angular 2+

Comment: did you find a solution for this?